# Summary Table From List -2010

Tags: list

I have a standard list with data such as this for different projects I am running

ProjectX|Green|Feb
ProjectY|Green|Feb
ProjectZ|Green|Feb
Project1|Red|Feb
Project2|Red|Feb
.....

How can I create a view with this data summarised

Feb|Green|2 
Feb|Red|2
Feb|Amber|1
March|Red|2
Feb|Amber|1

I dont have access to load any new webparts or anything like that, I am stuck with whatever the IT cops have given us. I am open to hacking at it with jQuery if that would work

Thanks,
Jerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do something with XSLT.  For a standard list view the XSL file can live in any document library so you would not need any special access so long as you can edit the page.

I have a post on how to create a project dashboard on my blog - http://paylord.wordpress.com

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom views can be done in the standard interface with no custom code. Just go to the list's main page, then the Library tab and you will see the option there.

Here is an [instructional video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftDgFIUEjxU).

If you are interested in hacking it with some jQuery take a looks at the [ListData.svc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521587%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (an OData web service that can return JSON). I use it in combination with [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/) to do a lot of different thing. If you want some more information on that, you should probably open a new question, though or edit this one to be more specific.

Here are some other topics you might wish to research:

[The Data View Web Part](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/10/16/create-dataview-webpart-in-sharepoint-2010-tutorial/)

[WebParts for View and Forms](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/web-parts-for-views-and-forms-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-HA101805424.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a plain, standard list view and use the grouping options. Group by the month, then by colour. Then total by project.

If you have access to SharePoint Designer, you can create a prettier result with a Data View Web Part instead of an XSLT List View.